# How to pass data received from dataService in parent to child in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a parent component **app-parent** and **app-child**. 
In **app-parent** I become a data from my DataService

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  providers: [DataService]
})

export class Part1Component implements OnInit {
  public title: string;

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.get().subscribe(data => {
      this.itemsSource = this.dataService.convert(data, 1);
      this.title = this.itemsSource[0];
          });
   return this.title;
  }
```

Template

```
 <div id="content">Hallo!</div>
    <app-child [title]='title'></app-child>
```

I would like to pass title to child component. 
So in my child component is:

```
@Injectable()
  export class InfoComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() title: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Show me title')
    console.log(this.title);
}
```

So, I try to use @Input() to pass my data, but it doesn't work (I become undefined instead if title). I guess, it is because in my parent component first I become data from DataService (because if I set title in **app-parent** to value in the beginning, like

```
  public title = 'Hola!';
```

it works.. )

Could you please tell me how could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is fetched asynchronously, so by the time child component `OnInit` is fired, `title` is yet to have a value. With `OnChanges` we can watch for changes in `@Input`, so what you can do is:

```
ngOnChanges() {
  console.log('Show me title')
  console.log(this.title);
}
```

which fires whenever there is changes in the Input `title`. If you need to do something with the `title`, you better set an `if` statement to check that it has value before trying doing anything with it, since at first executions(s) of `ngOnChanges`, `title` will be `undefined`.

As a sidenote, I don't know what you are trying to do with `return title` in your parent, but that won't return anything with value obtained from inside `subscribe`. Also, why is your child component marked as an `Injectable`? This is not relevant to your problem, but wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

when you navigate to the child view

```
 import { NavController,........} from 'ionic-angular';
 .
 .
 this.dataService.get().subscribe(data => {
  this.itemsSource = this.dataService.convert(data, 1);
  this.title = this.itemsSource[0];
  this.navCtrl.push(ChildPage, { title: this.title })
 });
 .
 .
```

and when you enter the child view

```
 import { NavParams,............} from 'ionic-angular';
 .
 .
 this.title = navParams.get('title')
 .
 .
```